# SQLite.Interop.dll not found on macOs

Tags: c#, .net, macos, sqlite, console-application

I've been having trouble connecting my console app under macOS with an SQLite Database. The program runs totally fine under Windows. If I execute it under macOS I always get a SQLite.Interop.dll not found Error. It's an macbook with M1 Chip. I added the System.Data.Sqlite Nuget and the Dapper Nuget. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I already tried another IDE, I tried to run it with Paralell Desktop (VM with Windows installed) and I tried it with multiple "testprograms". I'm just not able to connect with my SQLite Database in any program on my macbook and always get the describted error.

Again...it's exactly the same program. I have the folder structure in my iCloud and just run it from my Windows Desktop on my macbook.

```
public class SqliteDataAccess {

    public static List<PersonModel> LoadAllPersons() {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=testDataAccessDB.db")) {
            var output = connection.Query<PersonModel>("SELECT * FROM person");
            return output.ToList();
        }
    }
}


Programm.cs:

var list = SqliteDataAccess.LoadAllPersons();
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Name);
```

I just want to use SQLite on my Macbook with C#. I'm happy about any solution or alternatives.